# How to extract a quoted string using regular expression? OR  How to use this particular regular expression ("[^"]*\.csv") in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I am trying to extract a quoted text from an html response. However when i use regular expression to match the data i get the error message "Unrecognized escape sequence".
The code is pasted below. Am i missing something basic here?

---

```
    static private string ParseText2GetLink(string response)
    {
        Match match = Regex.Match( response, @"("[^"]*\.csv")" );

        string key = null;
        // Here we check the Match instance.
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
            key = match.Groups[1].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(key);
        }
        return key;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To include a double quotation mark in a `@""` string, you have to double it:

```
@"(""[^""]*\.csv"")"
```

Or you could use a normal string:

```
"(\"[^\"]*\\.csv\")"
```

(Note that now you have to escape the backslash.)

Comment: But will that not change the regular expression itself?

Comment: @MKV This has to do with C# string syntax, not regular expressions per se.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that \ in a string is an escape sequence. You have to escape the \ so it becomes

```
("[^"]*\\.csv")
```

Comment: ...and remove the @ so that the string is not a verbatim string literal (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)

Comment: The dot is a reserved character in regular expressions, and it looks like it's part of a file extension, so it would need to be escaped.

Comment: @Gonzalo Quero  Sorry your expression is giving the same error!